# fwrite adds an empty line at textfile

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, fwrite

I have a problem with `fwrite`. This is what I do. I get data from a textfile which I print into a table. After I print those values the user should be able to select the data which should be deleted (I do this with a key). So when he/she clicks on delete the file will post which key has to be deleted. All of that works. I update the array by deleting the key and that also works. But as soon as the data has to be rewritten into the textfile the file adds another space which causes that the array will have an "undefined offset" error. So I have to get rid of that blank line. This is my code 
:

```
 <?php

// Opening the required file
include("deletefunc.php");

$obj = new deletefunc();
$result = $obj->getMeData();
// Get posted value (The key that has to be deleted from the array)
$deleteKey = $_POST['rowNumber'];

$updateArray = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){
    if($i==$deleteKey){

    }
    else{
        $updateArray[$i] = $result[$i];
    }
}
var_dump($updateArray);

// Deleting data form textfile (Replacing)
$filename="phones.txt";
$file = fopen($filename,"w");
foreach($updateArray as $row){
    fwrite($file, $row);
}

?>
```

Comment: Is the empty line added where the line was removed?
I think I know what is your problem if it does.

Comment: Yes it adds a line where it has been removed. But the strange part is this is only if I delete the last one.

Comment: So it works fine removing any line except the last one?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have no idea what causes this.

Comment: Is your rowNumber beginning at 0 and finishing at numberOfRows - 1 ?

Comment: Yes it starts at 0. Adding data also works fine. I only get the error if I delete the last row. The rownumber is also fine. I checked it with `var_dump` to check the array. If it has 5 elements. It will as soon as I write it into the textfile it just adds another line.

Comment: What an element looks like?

Because with only number I have no problem with your code, so I guess your problem comes from your elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my guess :

Your problem comes from the fact that your element (except the last one) are ending with EndOfLine character...
So when you remove an element in the middle, no problem, but if you remove the last one, the one before has the EndOfLine character, and therefore you have an empty line in your file.

So basically you should add the EndOfLine character when writing to the file, and not keeping them in your elements.

To do so, you should use the `PHP_EOL` predefined constant which is the end of line character for adapted to the platform.

And if someone is wondering looking at that question, the `fwrite()` php function does NOT add EOL characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot I am going to figure this out with this information! :)